# как изменить код вызывающий ошибку

Tags: php, html, apache

Код писал в денвере, там все работает, выложил на другой сервер выдает ошибку

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in"

Локализовал проблему. Не работает из-за скрипта приведенного ниже, если его убрать, то все остальное отрабатывает нормально, как его можно изменить,  php занимаюсь не долго и в голову ничего не приходит

```
<p><select size="1" name="ppmd">
<option disabled>Выберите РМ</option>
<?php

$res = mysql_query("SELECT ppm_id, ppm FROM ppm");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
?>
    <option value=" <?=$row['ppm']?> "> <?=$row['ppm']?> </option>
<?
}
?>
</select></p>
```

Comment: строку `<?` стоит заменить на `<?php`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообщем сделал так, ошибка ушла и все заработало

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ppm'].'">'.$row['ppm'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить на

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['ppm']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ppm']; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Причина может быть в версии PHP, ибо краткая форма `echo` до версии 5.4 допускается только тогда, когда включена директива конфигурации `short_open_tag`

Вместо `<?=` стоит использовать `<?php`
Дополнительные варианты решения проблемы:

1. Включить `short_open_tag`;
2. Перейти на версию PHP 5.4+